# js leaflet give 403 error from mapbox at load tiles

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapbox, tiles

I use a leaflet 1.9.3 and i get 403 error from mapbox when load tiles, for example for this url

> https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/14/5353/10041?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw

My code is so simple, based on a documentation

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-37.6050,-62.3923], 15);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(mymap);
```

I use markers load via ajax to add a map

I migrate from version 1.7.1 to 1.9.3. In 1.7.1 i have some problem. I expecting resolve question before update but i still get same error at momento of load tiles.

Comment: Check that your `access_token` is a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox is a paid service with a generous free tier. One of its features is that it allows their users to restrict where their tokens can be used by URL.

It seems like you are using a "access_token" argument in your tile source that is restricted in such a manner. To resolve this, carry out the following:

1. Create a Mapbox account. This is free, and I believe you don't need a credit card. (https://account.mapbox.com/auth/signup)
2. In the Mapbox account page at (https://account.mapbox.com/), scroll down and look for your default public token. Copy that and use it in your app.

Doing these two steps will likely clear the initial 403-error and get you started.